# Showing images related to reviews

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to show my pictures related to my reviews. I am currently getting a -Property [pictures] does not exist on this collection instance. How would i go about retrieving the images related to the reviews.

Here is my tables
**Products**: id, name, price
**Reviews**: id, review, products_id_fk
**pictures**: id, image, Reviews_id_fk

Here are my models 
Product:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Reviews','reviews_id');
    }
}
```

Reviews:

```
class Reviews extends Model
{
    //
    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
    public function pictures()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Pictures');
        }

}
```

Pictures model:

```
class Picture extends Model
{
    //

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Reviews');
    }

}
```

ProductController:

```
public function getSingle($slug )
{
    //fetch from the database based on slug.
    $product = Products::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();





    //return view
    return view('products.single')->withProduct($product);

}
```

View blade:

```
        @foreach($product->reviews as $reviews)


                <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="content">


                    <div class="review-info">
                    <p>{{$reviews->review}}</p>

                </div>
                    <div class="images">
                        @foreach ($reviews->pictures as $picture)

                            <img src="{{asset('images/' . $picture->image)}}">




                        @endforeach


                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the foreign key name on the relation from Picture to Review.

The Picture model should look like:

```
class Picture extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
    public function review()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Review', 'Reviews_id_fk');
    }
}
```

The Review model should look like:

```
class Review extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'products_id_fk');
    }
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
    public function pictures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Picture', 'Reviews_id_fk', 'id');
    }
}
```

The Product model should look like:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Review','products_id_fk');
    }
}
```

Eloquent's naming convention by default is looking for a field named `review_id` on the pictures table, but since you named it differently, you need to specify it in the relationship method as I did above. With this you should be able to use the following:

```
@foreach($product->reviews as $reviews)
    ...
    @foreach($reviews->pictures as $picture)
        ...
        <img src="{{asset('images/' . $picture->image)}}">
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you change the name of the `Reviews_id_fk` field to `review_id` on the Picture model, you can omit specifying the foreign and local keys in the relationship methods.

I also changed the names of a couple of the methods from plural to singular to better follow conventions. Also models should be singular named as they represent a single entity. I've reflected that in changes above, as well.

You could also leave off the relationship between Picture and User as that is established via the Review model.

```
$picture->review->author
```

Comment: Man, i hear what youre saying but i still get the error. 

**Property [pictures] does not exist on this collection instance.** is it possible that the problem is that the first foreach is not allowing the second to enter its model as the reviews has been called through the $product?

Comment: Try adding `protected $with = ['pictures'];` to your Review model, seems like it's not eager loading pictures properly.

Comment: Comes back with the same problem. Property [pictures] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Missing something basic here... change the query for $product in your controller to

`$product = Products::with('reviews')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();`

Comment: Awesome! Eager loading can be a pain sometimes, keep in mind that when you set the `$with` property on a model, it forces it to query for that relationship every time, so it could get very costly performance wise!